# AJAX call gets a “400 bad request”

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery, i am getting `400` bad request (i find in browser console).

```
$("form#upload").submit(function(){
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
   var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
    url : '/uploadController/upload', 
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
  success: function (data) {
var msg=data.msg;
var obj=data.obj;   
 if(data.success == true)
{
$('#successmsg').html(msg);
$('.alert-success').show();
$('.alert-danger').hide();
 setTimeout(function() {
       $(".alert-success").alert('close');
   }, 10000);
}else {
$('#errmsg').html(msg);
$('.alert-danger').show();
$('.alert-success').hide();
setTimeout(function() {
       $(".alert-danger").alert('close');
   }, 10000);
}
       },
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
   });  
   return false;
 });
```

`POST url 400(Bad Request)`

Here console showing in error `$.ajax({` line on my js file.

But it working on some systems, i don't what is the problem.

Anyone has some ideas?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the error showing in console?

Comment: A bad request can be many things, normally I find it's using the wrong HTTP request method.

Comment: Most likely because the url is not correct

Comment: I believe, you need to `serialize` or `JSON.stringify` your `formData`

Comment: which is the absolute url your are targetting? have you tried putting the absolute url?

Comment: @Milan Chheda: I tried you code but i am getting `{"timestamp":1495777049660,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.Multip‌​artException","messa‌​ge":"The current request is not a multipart request","path":"/uploadController/upload"}`

Comment: @sTx: URL is correct

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can get serialized you form with this line:

`var formData = $(this).serialize()`

Use this formData in the ajax and it should work (assuming the relative URL to post is correct)

Comment: i tried your code, `{"timestamp":1495777049660,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException","message":"The current request is not a multipart request","path":"/uploadController/upload"}` but i am getting this error

Comment: You didn't comment that your server expects multipart request. Have you tried using `contentType: multipart/form-data`?